# Relationship between Indian monsoon and Indian ocean Dipole

Tags: geography

As we know that Indian monsoon basically involves a low pressure area over Tibet Plateau and a high pressure area near Mascarene basin. How come Positive Indian ocean dipole enhances the monsoon as it involves warm water accumulation near western Indian ocean which would create a low pressure area near Madagascar?

Comment: it does create a low pressure area near Madagascar but there is a heat low in the Rajasthan desert and that pulls the westerly winds towards the Indian subcontinent.  There is no low pressure area over Tibet. It is a high pressure in fact.